# connected components attributes in python

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, binary-image, connected-components

I want to compute statistics on the connected components of a binary image. In matlab we have

> Shape Measurements

```
    'Area'              'EulerNumber'       'Orientation'               
    'BoundingBox'       'Extent'            'Perimeter'          
    'Centroid'          'Extrema'           'PixelIdxList' 
    'ConvexArea'        'FilledArea'        'PixelList'
    'ConvexHull'        'FilledImage'       'Solidity' 
    'ConvexImage'       'Image'             'SubarrayIdx'            
    'Eccentricity'      'MajorAxisLength' 
    'EquivDiameter'     'MinorAxisLength'
```

Is there any equivalent in python?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147762/python-connected-components-with-pixel-list/38706369#38706369). Use the [`regionprops`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) function in scikit-image to get the CC properties in Python.

```
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label
from skimage.measure import regionprops
label = label(img)
props = regionprops(label)
# get centroid of second object
centroid = props[1].centroid
# get eccentricity of first object
ecc = props[0].eccentricity
```

The shape measurements output by `regionprops` include all the features listed above in the question. The `'PixelIdxList'` equivalent in Python is the `coords` property output by `regionprops`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I edited by answer to clarify and fully explain my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think openCV's cv2 interface is what you are probably looking for.

Answer (score 0):

as I know when Matlab try to find `'PixelIdxList'` consider the array as a 1D array and then count the indexes but in `regionprops[i].coords` bring back an array of arrays(2D array) that each inner arrays have two-element and by using them you can find the index values.

sth like this `x = [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],....,[xn,yn]]`.I try to implement the exact code of Matlab you can use if you want:

```
import skimage.measure as skme
import numpy as np

 
state = skme.regionprops(image)
for j in range(np.size(state)):
    s1 = state[j].coords
    flg = 0
    if np.size(s1,axis=0)>1:
        flg = 1
        InrList = []
        for k in range(np.size(s1,axis=0)):
            x1, y1 = state[j].coords[k]
            InrList.append(image[x1,y1])
        PixelIdxList.append(InrList)
    if flg == 0:
        x1, y1 = state2[j].coords[0]
        PixelIdxList.append(iamge[x1,y1])

# PixelIdxList is exact out put in Matlab
#STATS = regionprops(image,'PixelIdxList');          matlab
''' EACH ONE TEACH ONE '''
```